# Overcome the JQuery PHP Loader Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use a Loader in my Website in the checkout button.

So, Once the user click on the Checkout Button, The Loader will display for 5 seconds to according to the below given code.

As my checkout page executes too much of scripts on the  onclick of the checkout button, the loader is not working.  How can i over come it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#checkout_btn").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeToggle();
   $("#div1").fadeOut(2000);

  });
});
</script>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;display:none;background: url(http://s13.postimg.org/sdxi3qlkj/preload.gif) no-repeat center center;"></div>
```

Here is the click_checkout() function which validates lot of scripts takes place.

```
<div class="fw fl"><a class="gren s-shp" id="checkout_btn" onclick="click_checkout();">Check Out</a>
```

**What is the mistake i am doing, and How can i fix this ?**

Comment: Once, the scripts on the onclick() event is executed, run the fadeout code.

Comment: Does the user get redirected after the checkout script executes?

Comment: @TNC What's happening is, Once the onclick() is clicked the page starts executing php scripts which validates several parameters. So the jquery script functions is not viewable

Comment: @DavidJones NO i am not using any redirection in it

Comment: Your code seems rather confusing to me:
- Does the <div id="div1".. have anything to do with your problem? If not, please remove it. 
- why are you adding event handlers for the same object in two different places (inline and via JS). I'd prefer to add them all in one place via JS. Way easier to maintain.
- might help to see what click_checkout() does ..

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of event you need to set or use jQuery timecountdown.js . you can find full documentation this here http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/

And Here is your solution:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkout_btn").click(function() {

            $("#div1").fadeToggle();
            $('#hs_timer').countdowntimer({
                hours: 00,
                minutes: 00,
                seconds: 05,
                size: 'lg',
                timeUp: timeisUp
            });
            function timeisUp() {
              $("#div1").fadeOut();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
<div id="hs_timer" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;display:none;background: url(http://s13.postimg.org/sdxi3qlkj/preload.gif) no-repeat center center;"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, What happens is. Once i click the button, the page freezes (the validation process goes on) and once it was done, the image loader is showing for 5 seconds and disappear. Can't i play the timer or anything in the processing time ?